# jquery remove empty dropdowns

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a search form with some dropdowns which the user can leave empty. Now I want to remove these select elements before the form is submitted.

I tried this, but with this function all my select dropdowns are removed:

```
$('select option[value=""]').parent().remove();
```

Thanks for your help
cheers
dan

Comment: How do you left empty 'select'? just leave the first option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your selects all have an option with value `""` which is used as empty option.

Then your jquery call effectively removes all these selects.

When you want to select and remove the select elements where the user **did not set** another option you can write:

```
var s = jQuery("select").filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your view. When you create a select use an "empty" option like:

```
<form class="form">
    <select id="select1">
        <option value="-1"> - </option>
        ....
    </select>

    <select id="select2">
        <option value="-1"> - </option>
        ....
    </select>
</form>
```

Then when the form is submitted remove all the selects. I don't understand why you have to remove them... Are you making an Ajax call to submit the form?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form').submit(function(e) {
       var selects = $(this).find('select');

       $.each(selects, function(idx, value) {
          if($(this).val() === -1) {
              $('.form').find($(this).attr('id')).remove();
          }
       })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not work. And if you want to know why I want to do it that way: I'm working with a plugin that implements a database search which can only with one term at once. I wrote my own form which allows to search with multiple terms. But if the user doesn't need all fields for the search, it will be perfomed with empty values and therefore display some not desired results. And if I remove these fields before sending that won't happen and I don't have to fiddle on the plugins files and will be able to update the plugin without reenter my custom code into the new files.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that if the first option in selected - means that the dropdown wasn't selected, I suggest:

```
$("option:first-child:selected")
```

to select all first 'option' tags which are selected (by default, if none of the other options were selected.
Than you can choose their parent and remove as you did before.

Hope that's help